# How can I analyze the memory usage of my app built with Visual Studio Mac on iOS?

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

I built a .NET MAUI app using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. The app appears to be getting jettisoned on physical iOS devices due to high memory usage as indicated in Jetsamevent reports. How can I view the real-time memory consumption of my app while it's running in a simulator or physical device? I looked at the Visual Studio Tools->Instruments menu and don't see a solution. I don't see any relevant menu item in the simulators either.

I see there is an analyzer provided in Xcode but I don't know how to run the app I built with Visual Studio in Xcode.

I have seen a few suggestions of writing memory usage statements to a log, but that isn't the most efficient approach.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can profile your app without building it in Xcode. In Xcode choose Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Instruments to launch Instruments, the profiling that ships with Xcode. Connect the iOS device that has your app to your Mac.

When Instruments launches it will ask you for a template to use for recording. Select the Leaks template. The Leaks template measures your app's memory usage and reports any memory leaks.

On the left side of the Instruments window toolbar is a jump bar. Click on the leftmost item in the jump bar to open a menu. Choose your device from the left menu. Choose your app from the list of installed apps on the device. Click the Start Recording button to start recording.

The following article shows you how to read and interpret the data Instruments generates:

[Measuring Your App's Memory Usage with Instruments](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/measuring-your-apps-memory-usage-with-instruments/)

Comment: Thank you! I am able to launch the Instruments in Xcode and find the templates. However, I have two issues. First, when using the Leaks template, recording stops and "disconnects" from my app every time before I can capture any useful analysis. I can use the Activity Monitor to view all processes to see the memory consumption of my app indefinitely. However, that doesn't provide much detail. Secondly, I get "Activity monitoring service not available on this device." when trying to analyst the app on a simulator.

Comment: I can't fix your issues in a comment. Start by searching the tags `instruments` and `Xcode-instruments` here to see if anyone else asked a similar question. If not, ask a new question. I haven't profiled a .NET app with Instruments before so I don't know how well it supports .NET apps. I haven't profiled an app running on the iOS Simulator with Instruments so I don't know how well it works with the Simulator.